# Creating GUI desktop program with Python Tkinter on Treeview Why latest data is not shown in another page of Combobox by using postgresql database

Tags: python, postgresql, tkinter, treeview

I'm creating a GUI desktop program with Python using Tkinter on Treeview that interacts with a Postgresql database. The GUI displays all the contents in Treeview of a certain table when the program launches.

I have 2 tables when I have just added new data to table no.1 with column Id and Article.

Next, I will create new data in table no.2 by using data from table no.1. In this case, I would like to get the latest data but it is not shown in Combobox.

So my problem is why the latest data is not shown how can I fix it.

Here is the code that I need to get the latest data from the first table :

```
article_combobox = ttk.Combobox(wrapperArtForm, font=('Arial', 13), width=36)
article_combobox.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="w")
article_combobox['values'] = dbArticle.view_ArticleCol()
```

Also can see more detail in the image attachment.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IBMj.png)

Comment: There is no way we can reproduce your problem with that tiny bit of code.

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not comment).

Comment: I don't know what you try to do. Did you update data in combobox?  Better create minimal working code with example data so we could simply copy it and run it - and then we will see what exactly you try to do.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your comments and suggestions that allowed me to greatly improve next time and I am sorry to you all for my fault about less of code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the first code of form to input data to database:

```
class ArticleCreateWindow(Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller
    label = Label(self, text="Article - Create", font=controller.title_font, bg='#99ccff')
    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=(5,5))

    # Article Create Data
    #def article_create():
    wrapperArticleCreate = LabelFrame(self, text="Article - Create Data", font=('arial',10,))
    wrapperArticleCreate.place(x=130, y=34, width=1040, height=678)
    article_create_window = Frame(wrapperArticleCreate, bg="#e6ffe6")#, width=800, height=600)
    article_create_window.pack(fill="both", expand="yes", padx=10, pady=10)

    # Create Article Form to Enter Article Data
    wrapperArtForm = Frame(article_create_window, bg="#e6ffe6", width=1040, height=570)
    wrapperArtForm.place(x=0, y=0, width=1040)
        
    def insert_db():
        # Check Entry Form must be not Empty
        dataEntry = article_entry.get() and description_entry.get() and supplier_combobox.get()                  
        if dataEntry !="":
            # Check Duplicate Article Number?
            dbArticle.cur.execute("SELECT article FROM article WHERE article=%s", (article_entry.get(),))
            data = dbArticle.cur.fetchall()
            if not data:
                #print ("This Article is NOT Already Exists")
                dbArticle.insert(article_entry.get(), customer_number_entry.get(), description_entry.get(), supplier_combobox.get(), price_combobox.get(), unit_combobox.get(), lead_time_entry.get(), batch_combobox.get()
             
                def view_da(dbArticle):
                    trvArt.insert('', 'end', values=dbArticle.view_LastRow())
                view_da(dbArticle)
                controller.show_frame("ArticleMainWindow")
            else:
                #print ("This Article is Already Exists")
                ttk.tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Article - Create Data","This Article " + "< " + article_entry.get()  + " >" + " has already existed")
                #clear_fields() 
        else:
            ttk.tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Article - Create Data","Please Enter Data")       

    # Clear Text Field
    def clear_fields():
        id_entry.delete(0, END)
        article_entry.delete(0, END)
        customer_number_entry.delete(0, END)
        description_entry.delete(0, END)
        supplier_combobox.delete(0, END)
        price_combobox.delete(0, END)
        unit_combobox.delete(0, END)
        lead_time_entry.delete(0, END)
        batch_combobox.delete(0, END)


    #Button Control
    wrapperBtn = Frame(article_create_window, bg="#e6ffe6", width=1040, height=120)
    wrapperBtn.place(x=0 , y=602)
    btnSave = Button(wrapperBtn, text="Save", bd=1, width=8, height=1, font=('arial',12), fg="#404040", padx=13, pady=3, command=insert_db)
    btnSave.place(x=590, y=0)
    btnClose = Button(wrapperBtn, text="Reset", bd=1, width=8, height=1, font=('arial',12), fg="#404040", padx=13, pady=3, command=clear_fields)
    btnClose.place(x=720, y=0)
    btnClose = Button(wrapperBtn, text="Close", bd=1, width=8, height=1, font=('arial',12), fg="#404040", padx=13, pady=3, command=lambda: controller.show_frame("ArticleMainWindow"))
    btnClose.place(x=850, y=0)

    # Labels
    id_label = Label(wrapperArtForm, text="Id", font=('Prompt', 12)).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, padx=25, pady=8)
    article_label = Label(wrapperArtForm, text="Article *", font=('Prompt', 12)).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, padx=25, pady=8)
    customer_number_label = Label(wrapperArtForm, text="SCI Number", font=('Prompt', 12)).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W, padx=25, pady=8)
    description_label = Label(wrapperArtForm, text="Description *", font=('Prompt', 12)).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, padx=25, pady=5)
    supplier_label = Label(wrapperArtForm, text="Supplier *", font=('Prompt', 12)).grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=W, padx=25, pady=8)
    price_label = Label(wrapperArtForm, text="Price *", font=('Prompt', 12)).grid(row=10, column=0, sticky=W, padx=25, pady=8)
    unit_label = Label(wrapperArtForm, text="Unit *", font=('Prompt', 12)).grid(row=11, column=0, sticky=W, padx=25, pady=8)
    lead_time_label = Label(wrapperArtForm, text="Lead Time *", font=('Prompt', 12)).grid(row=12, column=0, sticky=W, padx=25, pady=8)
    batch_label = Label(wrapperArtForm, text="Batch Required *", font=('Prompt', 12)).grid(row=13, column=0, sticky=W, padx=25, pady=8)   

        
    # Entry Boxs 
    id_entry = ttk.Combobox(wrapperArtForm, font=('Arial', 13), width=5, values=["Auto"], state='readonly')
    id_entry.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W)
    id_entry.current(0)
    article_entry = Entry(wrapperArtForm, font=('Arial', 13), width=34)
    article_entry.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="w")
    customer_number_entry = Entry(wrapperArtForm, font=('Prompt', 13), width=34)
    customer_number_entry.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="w")
    description_entry = Entry(wrapperArtForm, font=('Prompt', 13), width=34)
    description_entry.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky="w")
    supplier_combobox = ttk.Combobox(wrapperArtForm, font=('Prompt', 13), width=32)
    supplier_combobox.grid(row=6, column=2, sticky=W) 
    supplier_combobox['values'] = dbSupplier.view_SupplierCol()
    price_combobox = ttk.Combobox(wrapperArtForm, font=('Prompt', 13), values=["0"], width=10)
    price_combobox.grid(row=10, column=2, sticky="w")
    price_combobox.current(0)
    unit_combobox = ttk.Combobox(wrapperArtForm, font=('Prompt', 13), values=["Pcs","Set"], width=10)
    unit_combobox.grid(row=11, column=2, sticky=W) 
    unit_combobox.current(0)
    lead_time_entry = Spinbox(wrapperArtForm, font=('Arial', 13), from_= 0, to = 20000, width=10)
    lead_time_entry.grid(row=12, column=2, sticky=W)
    batch_combobox = ttk.Combobox(wrapperArtForm, font=('Prompt', 12), values=['yes', 'no'], width=10)
    batch_combobox.grid(row=13, column=2, sticky=W)
    batch_combobox.current(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Next the second form to input data to the database in the different above table :

```
class ArticleConditionCreateWindow(Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller
    label = Label(self, text="Article Condition - Create", font=controller.title_font, bg='#99ccff')
    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=(5,5))

    # Article Condition Create Data
    #def article_create():
    wrapperArticleCreate = LabelFrame(self, text="Article Condition - Create Data", font=('arial',10,))
    wrapperArticleCreate.place(x=130, y=34, width=1040, height=678)
    article_create_window = Frame(wrapperArticleCreate, bg="#e6ffe6")#, width=800, height=600)
    article_create_window.pack(fill="both", expand="yes", padx=10, pady=10)

    # Create Article Condition Form to Enter Article Data
    wrapperArtForm = Frame(article_create_window, bg="#e6ffe6", width=1040, height=570)
    wrapperArtForm.place(x=0, y=0, width=1040)
        
    def insert_db():
        # Check Entry Form must be not Empty
        dataEntry = article_combobox.get() and supplier_combobox.get() and article_condition_combobox.get()      
        if dataEntry !="":
            dbArticleCondition.insert(article_combobox.get(), customer_number_entry.get(), description_combobox.get(), supplier_combobox.get(), article_condition_combobox.get(), price_combobox.get(), batch_combobox.get())                   
            def view_da(dbArticleCondition):
                trvArtCondition.insert('', 'end', values=dbArticleCondition.view_LastRow())
            view_da(dbArticleCondition)
            controller.show_frame("ArticleConditionMainWindow")
        else:
            ttk.tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Article Condition - Create Data","Please Enter Data")       

    # Clear Text Field
    def clear_fields():
        id_entry.delete(0, END)
        article_combobox.delete(0, END)
        customer_number_entry.delete(0, END)
        description_combobox.delete(0, END)
        supplier_combobox.delete(0, END)
        article_condition_combobox.delete(0, END)
        price_combobox.delete(0, END)
        batch_combobox.delete(0, END)    

    #Button Control
    wrapperBtn = Frame(article_create_window, bg="#e6ffe6", width=1040, height=120)
    wrapperBtn.place(x=0 , y=602)
    btnSave = Button(wrapperBtn, text="Save", bd=1, width=8, height=1, font=('arial',12), fg="#404040", padx=13, pady=3, command=insert_db)
    btnSave.place(x=590, y=0)
    btnClose = Button(wrapperBtn, text="Reset", bd=1, width=8, height=1, font=('arial',12), fg="#404040", padx=13, pady=3, command=clear_fields)
    btnClose.place(x=720, y=0)
    btnClose = Button(wrapperBtn, text="Close", bd=1, width=8, height=1, font=('arial',12), fg="#404040", padx=13, pady=3, command=lambda: controller.show_frame("ArticleConditionMainWindow"))
    btnClose.place(x=850, y=0)

    # Labels
    id_label = Label(wrapperArtForm, text="Id", font=('Prompt', 12)).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, padx=25, pady=8)
    article_label = Label(wrapperArtForm, text="Article *", font=('Prompt', 12)).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, padx=25, pady=8)
    customer_number_label = Label(wrapperArtForm, text="Customer Number", font=('Prompt', 12)).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W, padx=25, pady=8)
    description_label = Label(wrapperArtForm, text="Description", font=('Prompt', 12)).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, padx=25, pady=5)
    supplier_label = Label(wrapperArtForm, text="Supplier *", font=('Prompt', 12)).grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W, padx=25, pady=8)
    article_condition_label = Label(wrapperArtForm, text="Article Condition *", font=('Prompt', 12)).grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W, padx=25, pady=8)
    price_label = Label(wrapperArtForm, text="Price1", font=('Prompt', 12)).grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=W, padx=25, pady=8)
    batch_label = Label(wrapperArtForm, text="Batch No.", font=('Prompt', 12)).grid(row=8, column=0, sticky=W, padx=25, pady=8) 
        
    # Entry Boxs
    id_entry = ttk.Combobox(wrapperArtForm, font=('Arial', 13), width=5, values=["Auto"], state='readonly')
    id_entry.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W)
    id_entry.current(0)
    article_combobox = ttk.Combobox(wrapperArtForm, font=('Arial', 13), width=36)
    article_combobox.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="w")
    article_combobox['values'] = dbArticle.view_ArticleCol()
    customer_number_entry = Entry(wrapperArtForm, font=('Prompt', 13), width=38)
    customer_number_entry.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="w")
    description_combobox = ttk.Combobox(wrapperArtForm, font=('Prompt', 13), width=36)
    description_combobox.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky="w")
    description_combobox['values'] = dbArticle.view_DescriptionCol()
    supplier_combobox = ttk.Combobox(wrapperArtForm, font=('Prompt', 13), width=36)
    supplier_combobox.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=W) 
    supplier_combobox['values'] = dbSupplier.view_SupplierCol()
    article_condition_combobox = ttk.Combobox(wrapperArtForm, font=('Arial', 13), values=["New","Rework","Used","Dull","Blunt",""], width=10, state='readonly')
    article_condition_combobox.grid(row=5, column=2, sticky=W)
    #article_condition_combobox.current(0)  
    price_combobox = ttk.Combobox(wrapperArtForm, font=('Prompt', 13), values=["0"], width=10)
    price_combobox.grid(row=6, column=2, sticky="w")
    price_combobox.current(0)
    batch_combobox = Entry(wrapperArtForm, font=('Prompt', 12), width=12)
    batch_combobox.grid(row=8, column=2, sticky=W)
```

Comment: Why can't you edit the last answer with this.